# Stack arround variable is corrupted - adding simple class to std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a basic example of adding a class to a vector:

```
std::vector<AudioFile> audioList;
DllExport void add_audio(const char* srcFile, double startSecInSrc, double fromSecInMovie, double toSecInMovie, long id)
{
    AudioFile a(id, srcFile, startSecInSrc, fromSecInMovie, toSecInMovie);
    audioList.push_back(a);
}
```

at the end of the function I get the stack corrupted around variable a

What am I doing wrong?

```
    class AudioFile 
    {
         long _id;
         std::string _fileLocation;
         double _startSecInSrc, _fromSecInMovie, _toSecInMovie;
         double _duration;
         public:
         AudioFile(long _id, std::string _fileLocation, double _startSecInSrc,double _fromSecInMovie, double _toSecInMovie);
         ~AudioFile();
         static bool ComparePredicat(AudioFile first, AudioFile second);
    };

     bool AudioFile::ComparePredicat(AudioFile first, AudioFile second)
     {
          if (first._startSecInSrc <= second._startSecInSrc)
          return true;
          return false;
      }

       AudioFile::AudioFile(long id, std::string fileLocation, double startSecInSrc, double fromSecInMovie, double toSecInMovie)
      {
        _id = id;
        _fileLocation = fileLocation;
    _startSecInSrc = startSecInSrc;
    _fromSecInMovie = fromSecInMovie;
    _toSecInMovie = toSecInMovie;

             _duration = toSecInMovie - fromSecInMovie;
   }   AudioFile::~AudioFile()
   {
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is going on in the `AudioFile` class? Is it copyable? Is it moveable? What are its members? Did you define any of the constructors yourself, etc?

Comment: At minimum, post the code of the constructor of AudioFile, since that is central to the problem you are trying to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I added my class....I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried changing from const char* to std::string but it's the same thing. Apparently a becomes corrupt after the call to vector.push_back(a);

Comment: I never trust a code snippet that has completely bungled indenting in the code that matters most.  The simple explanation is that this code was compiled with the original declaration of AudioFile.  And thus doesn't allocate enough space for the object.

Comment: Is `srcFile` pointing to a valid C string?

Answer (score -2):

There may be more going on, but to make a new object and save it, yuou should declare a variable and then initialize it. Use the *new* keyword. I.e.     AudioFile a = new AudioFile(...); in your add_audio() fuction.

Also you could make your function slightly shorter ( but style could dictate how you want to write it) as:

```
audioList.push_back(new AudioFile(id, srcFile, startSecInSrc, fromSecInMovie, toSecInMovie));
```

Comment: There is no need for `new` here ; it's C++, not Java.